# In Android honeycomb OS can I move the Status bar to the top?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am working on a game and would like to move the status bar(navigation bar) to the top. I can imagine. The status bar getting in the way. Can be pushed accidentally during the game play easily.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered making your app full screen and removing it completely?

Comment: status(navigation) bar is a new UI element added to the honeycomb OS. Looks like you can't remove or move only dim it. I guess people are saying that it does not get in the way of the games.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this. The status bar has a "lights out" mode though. When turned on, the status bar buttons are dimmed. In my experience, the status bar never gets in the way when playing games.

Comment: Can you at least change its background color from black? How can you test the entire screen for dead pixels (cycling through primary colors - red, green, blue, etc.) if it remains black?

Comment: No you cannot change its color.